# cannot write/'w' FILE in function

Tags: c, function, file-io

I don't know what is wrong with this coding. I even use 'a' to output the display to for Name, Address, and Phone Number. for Read/'r' FILE my coding succefully run without any error but when try to Write FILE suddenly it cannot open the file or NULL.
[This is a snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNVtp.png)

**This is the function that I want to diplay the output in FILE of output.txt**

```
void display(char cName[], char cAddress[], char cPhoneNo[])
{
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    printf("\n_________________________________________________");
    printf("\n_________________________________________________");
    fprintf(output, "\n\n Name\t\t: %s", cName);
    fprintf(output, " Address\t: %s", cAddress);
    fprintf(output, " PhoneNo\t: %s", cPhoneNo);
    fclose(output);
}
```

**This is the whole coding**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void cookiesList(char[20][5], char* [], float*);
void infoInput(char[], char[], char[]);
int order(char* [], int*);
void display(char[], char[], char[]);
void outputDisplay(char[20][5], char[20][40], int[], float[], float, size_t, float, float, float, float);
float calculateSubTotal(float, int, float*);
float bundle(char*, char*, float);
FILE* input, * output;

int main()
{
    char customerName[50], customerAddress[70], customerPhoneNo[12];

    char productCode[20][5], productName[20][40];
    int productQuantity[20], decision, orderSubTotal=0;
    float productPrice[20], productPriceTotal[20];
    size_t counter = 0;

    float cashback, discount, finalprice;

    char bundleName[10], bundleItem[32];
    float bundlePrice;

    printf("\t\t\t#-------------------------------------------------------#");
    printf("\n\t\t\t|\t WELCOME TO ONLINE COOKIES PEOPLE STORE \t|");
    printf("\n\t\t\t#-------------------------------------------------------#\n");
    infoInput(customerName, customerAddress, customerPhoneNo);
    do
    {
        decision = order(&productCode[counter], &productQuantity[counter]);
        cookiesList(productCode[counter], &productName[counter], &productPrice[counter]);
        orderSubTotal = orderSubTotal + calculateSubTotal(productPrice[counter], productQuantity[counter], &productPriceTotal[counter]);
        counter++;
    } while (decision == 1);
    bundlePrice = bundle(&bundleName, &bundleItem, orderSubTotal);
    if ((15 <= orderSubTotal) && (orderSubTotal < 76))
    {
        cashback = 1.5;
        discount = 0;
    }
    else if ((76 <= orderSubTotal) && (orderSubTotal < 151))
    {
        cashback = 2.5;
        discount = orderSubTotal * 0.05;
    }
    else if (151 <= orderSubTotal)
    {
        cashback = 3.5;
        discount = orderSubTotal * 0.1;
    }
    finalprice = orderSubTotal - discount + bundlePrice;
    display(customerName, customerAddress, customerPhoneNo);
    outputDisplay(productCode, productName, productQuantity, productPriceTotal, orderSubTotal, counter
        , discount, cashback, finalprice, bundlePrice);
    return 0;

}

void cookiesList(char pdtCode[][5], char* pdtNm[], float* pdtprice)
{

    if ((strcmp(pdtCode, "c111") == 0) || (strcmp(pdtCode, "C111") == 0))
    {
        strcpy(pdtNm, "Dark Chocolate Chips");
        *pdtprice = 15.0;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(pdtCode, "c112") == 0) || (strcmp(pdtCode, "C112") == 0))
    {
        strcpy(pdtNm, "Premium Assorted Shortbread Cookies");
        *pdtprice = 25.5;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(pdtCode, "c113") == 0) || (strcmp(pdtCode, "C113") == 0))
    {
        strcpy(pdtNm, "Hawaiian Salted Coconut");
        *pdtprice = 17.5;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(pdtCode, "c114") == 0) || (strcmp(pdtCode, "C114") == 0))
    {
        strcpy(pdtNm, "Oatmeal & Raisins Cookies");
        *pdtprice = 13.0;
    }
    else if ((strcmp(pdtCode, "c115") == 0) || (strcmp(pdtCode, "C115") == 0))
    {
        strcpy(pdtNm, "Chocolate Caramel Almond Cookies");
        *pdtprice = 16.0;
    }
    else
    {
        exit(cookiesList);
    }
}

void infoInput(char cNm[], char cAdrs[], char cPhN[])
{
    input = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR! File does not have any input");
        return(-1);
    }
    else {

        //fgets(cNm, 50, fp);
        fscanf(input, "\n%[^\n]%*c", cNm);
        printf("\n Name entered\t\t: %s", cNm);
        //fgets(cAdrs, 70, fp);
        fscanf(input, "\n%[^\n]%*c", cAdrs);
        printf("\n Address entered\t: %s", cAdrs);
        //fgets(cPhN, 12, fp);
        fscanf(input, "\n%[^\n]%*c", cPhN);
        printf("\n Phone No. entered\t: %s", cPhN);
        printf("\n ----------------Product-------------------");
        printf("\n C111: Dark Chocolate Chips");
        printf("\n C112: Premium Assorted Shortbread Cookies");
        printf("\n C113: Hawaiian Salted Coconut");
        printf("\n C114: Oatmeal & Raisins Cookies");
        printf("\n C115: Chocolate Caramel Almond Cookies");
        printf("\n ------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    fclose(input);
}

int order(char* pdtCdLt[], int* pdtQtyLt)
{
    int YorN;
    printf(" Enter Product Code\t: ");
    scanf(" %s", pdtCdLt);
    printf(" Enter Quantity\t\t: ");
    scanf(" %d", pdtQtyLt);
    printf(" Want to add other product?( Yes = 1 | No = 0 ) ");
    scanf(" %d", &YorN);
    return YorN;
}

void display(char cName[], char cAddress[], char cPhoneNo[])
{
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    printf("\n_________________________________________________");
    printf("\n_________________________________________________");
    fprintf(output, "\n\n Name\t\t: %s", cName);
    fprintf(output, " Address\t: %s", cAddress);
    fprintf(output, " PhoneNo\t: %s", cPhoneNo);
    fclose(output);
}

void outputDisplay(char pdtCd[][5], char pdtName[][40], int pdtQty[], float pdtPriceTtl[], float odrSubTotal, size_t index
    , float disc, float CashB, float Fprice, float bdlPri)
{
    //yolo = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    /*if (yolo == NULL) {
        printf("Could Not open file!");
        return 0;
    }*/
    printf("\n Item\t\tQuantity\t\tPrice(RM)\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s", pdtName[i]);
        printf("\n %s\t\t%d\t\t\t%.2f", pdtCd[i], pdtQty[i], pdtPriceTtl[i]);

    }
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t============");
    printf("\n\t\t\t   Subtotal\t%.2f", odrSubTotal);
    if (bdlPri > 0)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t       Bundle Price\t%.2f", bdlPri);
    }
    if (disc > 0)
    {
        printf("\n\t\t\t   Discount\t%.2f", disc);
    }
    printf("\n\t\t\t   CashBack\t%.2f", CashB);
    printf("\n\t\t\tFinal price\t%.2f\n", Fprice);
    //fclose(yolo);
}

float calculateSubTotal(float pdtPri, int pdtQuanti, float* pdtPTtl)
{
    float subTtl;

    *pdtPTtl = pdtPri * ((float)pdtQuanti);

    return *pdtPTtl;
}

float bundle(char* bdlNm, char* bdlItm, float odrSubTtl)
{
    int yorn;
    float bdlPrice;

    printf("\n Do you want to choose any bundle?");
    printf("\n *Every bundle is RM 5 each.( Yes = 1 | No = 0 ) ");
    scanf(" %d", &yorn);
    if (yorn == 1)
    {
        printf("\n\t#-----------------------------Type of Bundle----------------------------#");
        printf("\n\t|\t\t\t|\t\t\t|\t\t\t|");
        printf("\n\t|\t Bundle A \t|\t Bundle B \t|\t Bundle C \t|");
        printf("\n\t|\tRecycle Bag\t|\tRecycle Bag\t|\tRecycle Bag\t|");
        printf("\n\t|\t    &    \t|\t    &    \t|\t    &    \t|");
        printf("\n\t|\t NoteBook \t|\tWater Bottle\t|\tMark Cup\t|");
        printf("\n\t|_______________________|_______________________|_______________________|\n");
    retry:
        printf("\n A = Bundle A, B = Bundle B, C = Bundle C ");
        printf("\n Choose Your wanted Bundle : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %c", &(*bdlNm));
        if ((*bdlNm == 'a') || (*bdlNm == 'A'))
        {
            strcpy(bdlItm, "Recycle bag and Notebook");

        }
        else if ((*bdlNm == 'b') || (*bdlNm == 'B'))
        {
            strcpy(bdlItm, "Recycle Bag and Water Bottle");
        }
        else if ((*bdlNm == 'c') || (*bdlNm == 'C'))
        {
            strcpy(bdlItm, "Recycle bag and Mark Cup");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n@~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~@");
            printf("\n{\t\t\t\t}");
            printf("\n }---------ERROR INPUT---------{");
            printf("\n{\t\t\t\t}");
            printf("\n@~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~@");

        }
        bdlPrice = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        bdlPrice = 0;
    }
    return bdlPrice;
}
```

Comment: If you want to display the content of a file, you should open it in "r" mode, as when you open it in "w"  mode, the file is overwritten and becomes empty

Comment: What are your OS and IDE?
If you are running this program in Windows, Please start IDE with "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

What are your OS and IDE?
I think that you are using Windows & VS now.
If you are running this program in Windows, Please start IDE with "Run as Administrator" like below.

[image]